# Finding the smallest increment of a number

Tags: javascript

Is there any built in capability in JavaScript that allows you to get the smallest increment of a certain number without expanding it? For example:

```
var i = 0.0003412
smallest increment = 0.0000001

var j = 0.011
smallest increment = 0.001
```

It's possible to calculate the length and throw a 1 at the end, sure. But is there a better way?

Comment: What does "expanding it" mean?

Comment: why .001 is the smallest increment for 0.011? Why not 0.00000000000001 e.g?

Comment: @phuzi it means exactly what the comment below yours asked. I don't want to expand amount of digits that a certain number has. I want to figure out based on the amounts of digits given, whats the smallest increment.

Comment: You should look up JS's number system: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp

Comment: @jrook look at my comment above, it replies to you too except I couldnt @ you for some reason :)

Comment: Would this extend in the other direction too?  `3412000 => 1000`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet No. in that case it would be 1.

Comment: @GalAppelbaum, I think strings are still the best way to achieve this. Theortically, you could do something like `while (Math.floor(x * 10^n) !== x * 10^n)) n++;` (n being the number of decimal points). But it will fail in practice due to the way computers handle floating point operations.

Answer (score 1):

a different approach to parsing the value.

```js
function smallestIncrement(nr) {
  if (nr < 0) nr = -nr;
  let str = nr.toExponential(),
    e = str.indexOf("e");

  return Number("1e" + (str.substr(e + 1) - Math.max(0, e - 2)));
}
//just for completeness
function biggestIncrement(nr) {
  if (nr < 0) nr = -nr;
  let str = nr.toExponential();
  return Number("1" + str.substr(str.indexOf("e")))
}

//floating point math has issues. like:
//0.1 + 0.2 === 0.30000000000000004
function fixFloat(v){
   return Math.round(v/1e-14)*1e-14;
}

[
  0.0003412,
  -3000,
  12.340,
  0.0000000123
].forEach(nr => {
  console.log(
    nr,
    fixFloat(nr+smallestIncrement(nr)),
    fixFloat(nr+biggestIncrement(nr))
  );
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100%!important
}
```

you stated that for values without decimal places, you want the step to be 1.

I didn't add that into the functions since I don't see, how/why there should be a difference in logic between `1.234e-10` and `1.234e+10`. 
You can clamp this by performing a simple `Math.min(1, smallestIncrement(nr))` or by changing the code to `return Number("1e" + Math.min(0, str.substr(e + 1) - Math.max(0, e - 2)));`

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in function for this, if that's your question. You would have to come up with a solution yourself. Something like this:

```
Math.pow(0.1, String(num).split('.')[1].length)
```