# Ruby: round to nearest increment, given a string

Tags: ruby

If i'm given a string like this: "0.00010000", how can I round to the nearest increment of this number?

```rb
smallest_increment = "0.00010000"
num = 2.23678301
```

I want: `2.2367` but if I don't know the smallest_increment ahead of time I don't think I can use `.round(4)`. How can I take in any number and round to the nearest value, like "1.0", or "0.001".

I tried using BigDecimal ([per this blog posts suggestions](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/50fe886f68fc44056f00626c)), but this too did not yield the correct results:

I've found some similar questions answered in JS, but am not seeing how I can do this with ruby: [Finding the smallest increment of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654082/finding-the-smallest-increment-of-a-number)

Comment: Will `smallest_increment` always be identified by the same notation e.g. "0.0","0.1","0.01","0.001", etc ? or could it be `smallest_increment = "0.0234567"` and the increment would be based on the least or most significant digit that is non zero?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```rb
f = smallest_increment.to_f
(num / f).floor * f
```

Your question is a bit unclear, because you say round but then proceed to floor the number. You might want to replace floor with round.

Comment: This works, I think I can combine this with bigdecimal for better precision, because the above can result in "0.29123000000000004" etc.

Comment: Small caveat `smallest_increment = "0.0"` will result in a `ZeroDivisionError`